# How to set custom font for RecyclerView items

Tags: android, android-fonts

I am a beginner at android. I created a `RecyclerView` by parsing JSON data. I want to make this TextView font in `RecyclerView` items custom. I tried many methods but it didn't work for me. I want to set a custom font as my font in a text view in `RecyclerView` item. Please help me
My adapter code:

```
public class ExampleAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter <ExampleAdapter.ExampleViewHolder>{
    private Context mContext;
    private ArrayList<ExampleItem> mExampleList;
    private onItemClickListener mListener;
    public interface onItemClickListener{
        void onItemClick(int position);
    }

    public void setOnItemClickListener(onItemClickListener listener){
        mListener = listener;
    }
    public ExampleAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<ExampleItem> examplelist){
        mContext =context;
        mExampleList = examplelist;
    }


    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ExampleViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
       View v = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.example_item,parent,false);
       return new ExampleViewHolder(v);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ExampleViewHolder holder, int position) {
        ExampleItem currentItem = mExampleList.get(position);
        String imageUrl = currentItem.getmImageUrl();
        String creatorName = currentItem.getmCreator();
        String cat =currentItem.getmCat();

        holder.mTextViewCreator.setText(creatorName);
        holder.mTextViewCat.setText(cat);
        Glide.with(mContext)
                .load(imageUrl)
                .into(holder.mImageView);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mExampleList.size();
    }

    public class ExampleViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
public ImageView mImageView;
public TextView mTextViewCreator;
public TextView mTextViewCat;
        public ExampleViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            mImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.image_view);
            mTextViewCreator = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_view_creator);
            mTextViewCat = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_view_cat);
            itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    if(mListener != null){
                        int position = getAdapterPosition();
                        if (position !=RecyclerView.NO_POSITION){
                            mListener.onItemClick(position);
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the .ttf files of your font inside res/font folder of your project, then use it in your xml layout using the fontFamily attribute, for example:

```xml
<TextView
  android:id="@+id/yourTextView"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:fontFamily="@font/your_font_name"/>
```

Reference here: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/fonts-in-xml

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to create a folder in assets called fonts and put your own font in it. Just like this
[image]

Then, you can use the setTypeface() method like this(add this code in your onBindViewHolder() method)

```
AssetManager am = getContext().getApplicationContext().getAssets();
Typeface typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(am, "fonts/Raleway-Medium.ttf");
holder.mTextViewCreator.setTypeface(typeface);
holder.mTextViewCat.setTypeface(typeface);
```

Answer (score 0):

To use an specific font in a TextView you need create a folder called "fonts" in assets

And you can use a custom font setting the typeface to the TextView like that:

```
TextView txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.custom_font);
Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "Chantelli_Antiqua.ttf");
txt.setTypeface(font);
```

But if you want use a custom font in more views, the good way is create your own TextView and set the type face and use it in the differents layouts to avoid duplicate the code above.

Answer (score 0):

You can Try adding default Google fonts available in android studio in design tab. you can search for fontFamily and then click on more fonts. in this way the font will be added automatically in XMl. it will work for API Level above 17[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/genUn.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Android 8.0 (API level 26) introduces a new feature, Fonts in XML [docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/fonts-in-xml)

[image]

Layout:

```
 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_title"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fontFamily="@font/gotham_htf_book"
    android:text="@string/title" />
```